# Question on differentiate under integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

First we have the following theorem:
[image]

Then we apply it to a concrete problem:
[image]

Finally how to obtain the second rectangle?

Comment: Note that it doesn't converge with the *lebesgue measure* i.e. $\mu = m$, but we're given by assumption that it does converge for $\mu = P_Z$ where $P_Z$ denotes the probability measure associated with $Z$

Comment: @DanZimm oh I see. Could you give me some advice on the second rectangle? In fact ,I don't to how to deal with $s$

Comment: @paradox I don't follow what you mean by second rectangle, could you explain?

Comment: @DanZimm I mean the second red rectangle in the picture.

Comment: Hrm just realized my initial reasoning isn't necessarily right - in the problem you're given do you have any information about $Z$? In other words what measure space is it defined on? My original suggestion was in assumption that you were working with a bounded set of $\mathbb{R}$ so that you could have $C = \sup s$ or something similar. Unfortunately now I'm not completely sure where that inequality comes from.

Comment: This is a very simple estimate (your bounty is too generous): Since $|x|<\delta$ by assumption, we certainly have that $e^{sx}\le e^{\delta |s|}$. Moreover, $|s|\le C e^{\delta |s|}$ also, and now we recall that $\epsilon=2\delta$ and remove the absolute value in the exponent by passing to the sum of the two exponentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement we are trying to prove is:
$$|s|e^{xs}\leq C(e^{-\epsilon s}+e^{\epsilon s}),\qquad\mbox{for $x\in[-\frac{\epsilon}{2},\frac{\epsilon}{2}]$}$$
Note that $C$ must be independent of $x$ and $s$, but is allowed to depend on $\epsilon$.

Make the following choice:
$$
C=\max_{t>0}te^{-\epsilon t/2}<\infty.
$$

To prove the bound, consider the case $s>0$. Then $C\geq se^{-\epsilon s/2}\geq se^{(x-\epsilon)s},$ so
$$
|s|e^{xs}=se^{xs}\leq Ce^{\epsilon s}\leq C(e^{\epsilon s}+e^{-\epsilon s}).
$$
In the case $s\leq 0$, replace $s$ with $-s$; the inequality to prove is
$$
se^{-xs}\leq C(e^{\epsilon s}+e^{-\epsilon s})\qquad s\geq 0.
$$
This follows from the same argument, since $C\geq se^{-\epsilon s/2}\geq se^{(-x-\epsilon)s}$.